# Android Client to Server Node.js through Firebase for Payment

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase

I'm a little confusing about all that stuff, I'm an android developer, now I need to integrate payment in my app, so I used paypal gateway but I need a server, so I used firebase telling me that i need to use node.js. I don't know it, but still I tried to do what I found on the net, here's my code, if someone could explain to me where I'm wrong or if there is a simpliest way !? Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID =
            "Here there is my actual client id";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING = 3;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
            .merchantName("Example Merchant")
            .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
            .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.buyItBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("0.01"), "USD", "sample item",
                        PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
                intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.futurePaymentBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.profileSharingBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PayPalProfileSharingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
                intent.putExtra(PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_REQUESTED_SCOPES, getOauthScopes());
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING);
            }
        });

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);
    }

    private PayPalOAuthScopes getOauthScopes() {
        Set scopes = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(PayPalOAuthScopes.PAYPAL_SCOPE_EMAIL, PayPalOAuthScopes.PAYPAL_SCOPE_ADDRESS));
        return new PayPalOAuthScopes(scopes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    Log.i(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    //TODO: envoyer 'confirm' et si possible confirm.getPayment() à votre server pour la vérification
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PayPalAuthorization auth =
                    data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
            if (auth != null) {
                String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                sendAuthorizationToServer(authorization_code);
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PayPalAuthorization auth = data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
            if (auth != null) {
                String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                sendAuthorizationToServer(authorization_code);
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendAuthorizationToServer(String auth) {

    }
}
```

That's my code in my index.js in my functions folder :

```
var braintree = require("braintree");

var express = require('express'),
  app = express();

var gateway = braintree.connect({
  environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
  merchantId: "actual merchand id",
  publicKey: "actual publicKey",
  privateKey: "actual privateKey"
});

var gateway = braintree.connect({
  accessToken: "actual accesstoken"
});

app.get("/client_token", function (req, res) {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    res.send(response.clientToken);
  });
});

app.get("/checkout", function (req, res) {
  var nonce = req.body.payment_method_nonce;
  // Use payment method nonce here
});
```

Tell me if some files or code are missing, also how do I call a function in my index.js file from my android code ?? 
Thanks !

Comment: What should have happened and what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

your index.js is missing a port for it run on try adding these lines

`var port = '3333';
app.set('port', port);`

Try accessing your server if u are running on local machine with node js
You will have a file known as **package.json** make sure u have *braintree* and *express* inside **dependencies** then run `npm install`
use the command `node index.js` to start the server

You should be able to access both the get methods using

> http://localhost:3333/checkout or /client_token

Comment: OK tanks ill try that as soon as possible, the only thing is that i already have a http address by firebase is that changing anything ?

Comment: No it should not as long as your server is running the concept is the same check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, when i'm trying to access it through android it's saying : java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 3333) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) ! Plus when i'm clicking on the link http://localhost:3333/checkout  i end up nowhere, is that normal ?

Answer (score 0):

I have two functions one work not the other one here they are, could you explain me why , bigben works not the other one the app.get :
functions is equal to firebase-functions !

```
exports.bigben = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const hours = (new Date().getHours() % 12) + 1 // london is UTC + 1hr;
  res.status(200).send(`<!doctype html>
    <head>
      <title>Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      ${'BONG '.repeat(hours)}
    </body>
  </html>`);
});

app.get("/client_token", function(req, res) {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    res.send(response.clientToken);
  });
});
```

So i tried to rewrite the second as the first but i ended up with that, and without knowing js i know something is wrong here :

```
exports.tokenclient = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
  res.send(response.clientToken);
});
```